# Internet connection lost after signing in to client network

Tags: networking, ssh

In our project, we use the RSA tokens to sign-in to our client network to get access to the databases we need for local development as well. The database is in critical area and gets updated every 5mins so we cannot have a replica on our local work network.

The problem is that after signing-in to the client network, we lose internet connectivity and If I want to search for something very small while code development, I have to search it over my phone or access one of the PC on their network to do so. Either way, I lose the flow and pace I'm working and its quite irritating at times.

Is there any way I can be on client's network and not lose the internet connectivity provided by office LAN at the same time so that I can work more productively?

Comment: Likely the software for the client network is configured to push a default route to you. See if it can be configured not to do that.

Comment: No, it does not allow that. It's just a basic proprietary tool to sign-in with the credentials and then it minimizes down to the system tray (notification area) giving us the access to their network

Comment: I think what you should ask for is split tunneling

Comment: And how is that gonna help ? Please provide more info on that. I'm not a networking guy

Comment: @Shubham Check your routing table. I bet you'll find a new default route.

Comment: After logging in to their network, I did found multiple routes adding to my route table. But cannot identify the default route and also, how is that gonna help me to solve my problem?

Comment: In case of VPN connection then you will be in the client network.If the client firewall is blocking the other connection then u cant access the internet.

Comment: @Amaresh Ok. Seems to be the right answer but demoralizing at the same time :-P
Thanks all :-)

Comment: @Shubham If you can identify the route that's causing the problem, you can simply remove it. Do you know how to recognize a default route? What OS are you using?

Comment: @David No, I have no clue. I'm using Windows 7 Pro. Here is the difference between the routing tables before and after sign-in --- [Routing table diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/vinvupvq)

Answer (score 0):

Your default route (the one with `0.0.0.0` as the destination and mask) changed. You can just change it back with this command (from an elevated command prompt):

```
 route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1
```

But you should see if you can get the tool reconfigured not to push a useless default route to you or not to accept it.

Comment: Is this a irreversible process?

Comment: You can change it back again if you want. Likely the VPN tool you're using will change the default route every time it is started and stopped. Worst case, rebooting the machine should restore the original configuration since this is not permanent.

Comment: Okay. So, I'll be able to use the benefits of both the network after doing this or I will lose the client network connectivity and gain back my internet?

Comment: I would expect you'll get both, but I can't be positive. It's possible that the client network was only reachable through the new default route. That's unlikely, but you never know. Try it and see.

Comment: After doing so, my tool just popped up that it got terminated unexpectedly and would like to reconnect. Seems like the unlikely is true.
Thanks for helping out though. Really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Shubham Yeah, sorry. Sounds like the tool is designed to work in this particular way. :(

Comment: It's alright. I got to know a little about networking from you. Thanks for that :-)